# SSRS Adjacent grouping in matrix report

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, report, grouping, hierarchy

I have a question related to SSRS matrix report.  I have data captured in the following format in the table:

### Category    Name    Month   Cost

### C1  N1  M1  10

### C1  N1  M2  20

### C1  N1  M3  30

### C1  N2  M1  40

C1  N2  M2  50

### C1  N2  M3  60

### C2  N3  M1  70

### C2  N3  M2  80

### C2  N3  M3  90

So basically it captures the category, the product name and costs for various months.
What I want to have in my report is something like this:

### Category    Name    M1  M2  M3

### C1  N1  10  20  30

### C1  N2  40  50  60

### C1  N3  70  80  90

So this is similar to pivot on months with Category and Name as static columns. When I try to create two groups, Category and Name, in the matrix report, the Category becomes the parent group and the report groups all the products in common categories. For example I am getting something like this:

### Category    Name    M1  M2  M3

### C1  N1  10  20  30

### N2  40  50  60

C1  N3  70  80  90

I don’t want above grouping. I want category c1 to be repeated for N1 and N2.
I am kind of novice in matrix report and maybe I missing some obvious group settings. Can someone please help me in this?

EDIT: I am using SSRS 2008 R2
Thanks & Regards
AK

Comment: What version of SSRS is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a matrix style Tablix in SSRS it will look like this be default:

[image]

[image]

The reason *C1* is displayed like this is that by default group headers are not added to the Tablix body area and are only shown once per group.

Note that `Category` and `Name` are to the left of the dotted lines:

[image]

See [Understanding the Tablix Data Region](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220587%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Delete the two left columns. When prompted, choose **Delete columns only**:

[image]

Now, add two columns like below:

[image]

The tablix now looks like this:

[image]

Note there is no longer dotted lines between `Name` and `Month`, i.e. everything is in the Tablix body region.

Now the end result looks like your requirement:

[image]